# XSLT 2.0: Substring-after on a for-each loop to get distinct-values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input XML:

```
<img src="blah.jpg"/>
<img src="blahh.jpg"/>
<img src="blah.gif"/>
```

I need a distinct output string of filetypes, in the format:

```
jpg|gif
```

My existing stylesheet gets some of the way:

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(descendant::img/@src)">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-after(.,'.'),'|')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'.')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, I get a duplicated file type because I can't put the substring-after in the for-each loop (it throws an error as you can't do a substring-after on multiple strings at once). This means I can only get distinct-values of the entire @src attribute (not the string after the period). So my output currently looks like this:

```
jpg|jpg|gif
```

I'd be really appreciative of a simple XSLT 2.0 solution that enables me to do this.

Many thanks for your time in advance - really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you should be able to do this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(descendant::img/(substring-after(@src, '.')))">
```

That should return just "jpg" and "gif".

Better still, do away with the **xsl:for-each** altogether, and just do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(descendant::img/(substring-after(@src, '.')))" 
              separator="|" />
```

Of course, this assumes all your file names just have one `.` in. A file name like "my.file.gif" would cause issues.

Comment: That's the ticket - thanks very much. =D For those who stumble upon the same issue, you'll need to remove the substring-after() from the two value-of statements in the for-each, else you won't get an output.

Comment: To account for filenames with multiple `.`, you could do `tokenize(@src,'.')[last()]` instead of substring-after.